# Resolving resultant force into the components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors

I hate to use this medium in the wrong way, and I understand the fundamental principles to this question. However, The question goes that you must resolve the resultant force (R=500N) into its components along the u and v axis, as shown in the following diagram. Sorry for it being sideways.

[image]

From this I figured that the force must be 500N in the u axis, and 0N in the v axis. Is this correct, or am I missing something fundamental, and there is an actual magnitude of force in the v direction.

Comment: I don't see how $R$ can be decomposed into $u$ and $v$-components, as all of $R$ lies on $u$. Or what would even be the point in doing this...

Comment: But, $u$ and $v$ are not perpendicular components, isn't the $v$ component $R\cos(30)$?

Comment: That's my point @Gert. It feels like a redundant question right? This is a question from a previous exam paper which I am using to prepare for finals.

Comment: @Vishwaas that is what I am trying to get clarity on. In my mind it doesn't make sense to have a v-component because it doesn't have one.

Comment: @Vigi: it's a trick question or a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

on solving the equation the v=0
and u= (-500) according the equation

the resolution in not in the quadrant of the resultant so the resolution is negative in this case.[image: the resolution of the forces in the plane]

i think this is the answer
if the second equation is not considered there are infinite possibilities

Answer (score 1):

There is no $v$ component.

I understand the source of confusion, and non-perpendicular coordinate system axes are only very rarely used in practise since each axis then is not uniquely defining their own direction but "overlaps" with the other directions. And at the same time the usual definitions of cosine and sine are not directly usable to find the components anymore, since these are defined for perpendicular axes.

Here there is no $v$ component and you see that simply from a geometric view point: The components must be able to be added to give the resulting vector. But if you add any $v$ component then you are off course and can never reach the resulting vector in your case, because the direction is changed.

Comment: This is exactly my thinking also. However, why is it that others believe it is possible to have some force in the v-component? I cannot accept this as an answer simply because I would only be accepting it as it goes with what I believe is correct. Whose fundamental intuition is broken? Ours or the ones saying it is possible?

Comment: Who says it's possible? You don't have to "believe" anything to be correct. If you understand the point of components, then you will know that any vector can be split into it's components along the defined coordinate axes, and the sum of these components (as if you draw them end to end) must give the vector again. Understanding this solves the question.